# [Android]Show status bar and navigation bar programmatically while in Immersive sticky mode

Tags: java, android

I use the following code to enter Immersive sticky mode in Android.

```
mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

**What I want is:** I want the status bar and navigation bar to show when I touch the center part of my Activity instead of swiping from the edge. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write any additional code (just call some methods) then use SystemUIHelper from here: https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/73de18faffca571f7292

and then something like this:

```js
...

    SystemUiHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.[Your content view]);
        uiHelper = new SystemUiHelper(this, [Your flags/modes]);
      
        // Then set onTouchListener on youк root view
        // and when someone touch it you will receive an event about it 
        // and will be able to manage it and hide/show app's UI again
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (uiHelper.isShowing()){
                    uiHelper.hide();
                }else{
                    uiHelper.show();
                }
                break;
        }
      
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```